# Weird Issue on a benchmark in PHP

Tags: php, casting, benchmarking, microtime

I have wrote this snippet to test the time that it takes to cast a string to integer and I tried this one here for fun but the result was so interesting.

```php
<?php
$s = "123456789";
$t = microtime(true);
$data["HI"] = $s;
echo json_encode($data);
$time1 = (microtime(true) - $t);

$t = microtime(true);
$data2["HI"] = $s;
echo json_encode($data2);
$time2 = (microtime(true) - $t);

if($time1 > $time2) {
  echo "yes";
  echo $time1;
  echo $time2;
}

?>
```

**Result**

```
yes
$time1 => 1.2874603271484E-5
$time2 => 3.0994415283203E-6
```

The weird thing is why would the same code take more time to run?

Comment: I have tried this on my machine, and get the same differences, but I think it can be explained by CPU architecture, in that in the first instance the code is loaded into the CPU to run, incurring some time being taken from disk, through RAM, to the CPU. The second instance has no need to recall the process through the same path, but rather to use what is already there. I verified this by modifying your test to run 3 times, with the following scores: 1.5020370483398E-5 5.0067901611328E-6 5.0067901611328E-6. See how it is the same the third time? Everything is already available to the CPU.

Comment: @Onyx I think we should test this code for like a million times for the avg benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

:) ok @Mahdi Bagheri

```
 <?php
function dowork(){
$s = rand(100000,999999);
$t = microtime(true);
$data["HI"] = $s;
$j= json_encode($data);
$time1 = (microtime(true) - $t);
return $time1;
}
$avg = 0; $limit = 1000000; $start = date("h:i:sa");

  for($x=1 ;  $x<=$limit; $x++){
      $avg = ($avg + dowork())/$x;
      print "Iteration: ".$x. " Average = ". $avg ."\r\n";
}

print "Starting time is " . $start."\r\n";
print "Ending time is " . date("h:i:sa")."\r\n";
print "Average=".$avg;
?>
```

My results:

Starting time is 09:21:05am

Ending time is 09:21:12am

Average=9.5367527008247E-13

This is on an Asus G531T laptop with i9-9750 CPU.

For anyone else who wishes to play with this, DON'T run it in your web page, only at the CLI with the likes of :
$ php /path/to/test.php   or you could crash the browser. It is certainly faster at CLI, and formatted for it with line feeds rather than breaks.

Comment: every action, including echo'ing, calculating and concatenating takes time, even using double quotes over single ones or the response time of the tty, it get to a point when the code your wrapping around the test takes longer then what your testing, though point is made that php has an op cache

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Absolutely. This is more an exercise in showing the OP that the initial time to load is a lot longer than subsequent calls to the same code, but also that subsequent calls are not all equal in their time taken either.